# Notification Icons on second monitor shows blank context menu

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, notification-area

If I move my taskbar to my second monitor and right click any of the windows notification area icons (e.g sound and network connectivity) the context menu shows up blank, pictures below:

[image: sound notification are icon blank example]

[image: network notification area icon blank example]

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are either of the monitors a touch screen by any chance?

Comment: no, 2 28" monitors one is 1080p and one is 4k

Answer (score 2):

Issue seems to be when the other (primary) display is set to different dpi scaling options then the secondary monitor the task bar is on. Change them both to the same scaling fixed it for me.